# checking if year is in the string (4 consecutive digits)

Tags: python, list, match

How can I find if a strings in a list contains a year (ex. `1999`).  I guess I would check for four consecutive digits such as: `[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

How to check that against a list piece?  Here is what I've tried already

```
for piece in reflist:
    if "\d{4}" in piece:
        # Do something

for piece in reflist:
    if re.match('\d{4}', piece):
        print piece + '\n'
```

Comment: `re.match` only checks from the start of the string. Try `re.search`. On a side note you should use raw strings `r'...'` for regex patterns.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What do you expect your code to do, where does it fail to do that, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use `re.search()` to test for matches *anywhere* in the input string.

To match (recent) years a little more precisely, you could use:

```
re.search(r'[12]\d{3}', piece)
```

which would match anything from 1000 through to 2999.

Comment: @MartijnPieters When I attempt your solution I get an object that I can't seem to make tell me what the actual match is.  How do I get the match?

Comment: I found it.  If `m = re.search(r'[12]\d{3},piece)` then `m.group(0)` will give you the match.

Answer (score 2):

While both `'\d{4}'` and `r'[12]\d{3}'` will return 4 consecutive digits, they will also return the first 4 digits of a larger number like 199999.

To get an occurrence of a year like the OP example of `1999`, wrap the expression with `\s` which will match for whitespace characters.

```
r'\s[12]\d{3}\s'
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the answers above - `'r'\s[12]\d{3}\s'` misses the edge cases where the 4 digit number appears at the beginning or end of the string, or the string consists only of the date (because there is no space before or after the date in those cases). To capture those cases, use the below (the original plus the three edge cases):

`re.search(r'^[12]\d{3}\s|\s[12]\d{3}\s|\s[12]\d{3}$|^[12]\d{3}$', piece)`